# Java BufferedWriter - newLine() method

Tags: java, file, newline, bufferedwriter

I have been encountering a problem for a while now, and have tested every possibility I can think of. Unfortunately, these possibilities did not work.

Basically, I am trying to write to a .txt file using BufferedWriter in Java. I need this setup so that I can have a line in between each piece of data. Imagine this is the text file produced from Java, it should look like this:

```
line1

line2
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path path = Paths.get("test.txt");

    if (!Files.exists(path)) {
        try {
            Files.createFile(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error in creating test.txt! Read the stacktrace 
            below.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset)) {
        String string = "line1";
        writer.write(string, 0, string.length());
        writer.newLine();
        writer.newLine();

        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to write to file! Read the StackTrace below.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset)) {
        String string = "line2";
        writer.write(string, 0, string.length());

        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to write to file! Read the StackTrace below.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output of this produces a text file as so:

```
line2
```

Now, I know I could just combine my two try/catches, and it would work. But this is just a test representation; in my real code, I need to do this separately so I can write in .txt files whenever specific events are triggered.

Basically, the newLine() methods are not *saving* unless I write text directly after them.

Any help is appreciated, as always!

Comment: Are you sure that the issue isn't that when you reopen your file you're overwriting what's already there?

Comment: You can use `Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;` as StandardCharsets lists as constants all Charsets that are always available in any JRE (unlike ISO-8859-3). No UnsupportedEncodingException!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second BufferedWriter, or rather the second implicit FileWriter, overwrites the file created by the first one.

Combine the statements as you suggest, or use append mode (inefficient in this case).

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to combine the statements, you could maintain a reference to the writer throughout your application.

Comment: I cannot combine it as I said due to my needs. How can I append it?

Comment: `Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset, StandardOpenOption.APPEND)` for the second.

Comment: Or just follow @IstvanChung's suggestion.